# Sorting Arrays when it displying in tableview

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios4

I have two arrays one is for names and another is for phone numbers,and when I import phone contacts names to first array(names array) and the appropriate numbers also in another array(numbers array),the problem is when I display this two arrays in a tableview with sorting order.

How can I sort this two arrays and display it in tableview. Please help me.

Comment: What array are you using..normal C array or NSArray (or NSMutableArray)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name"
                                              ascending:YES] autorelease];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [yourName sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

you can also sort based on phone numbers (pass name of your phone number variable instead of name as key to initWithKey). Hope this helps..

Also I think you only need to use one Array, Create an NSDictionary object which has name and phone numbers as members, Then create a NSMutableArray of this dictionary object is the best way to go..